# Master UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I used the code that was placed by Alexander: [I want a Master UserControl (a Master page, but for UserControls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334204/i-want-a-master-usercontrol-a-master-page-but-for-usercontrols)

I have a question to this code. How to access controls (eg ListBox) that I have in MasterControl1 of ChildControl1.ascx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've always done it is to expose the controls via a method.

So if you want to access the ListBox, make a method in the Master User Control like this:

```
public ListBox GetListBox()
{
    return this.myListBox;
}
```

So since this is a little different than MasterPages, from the child control, you'll need to do the following:

```
var master = (MasterControl1)Page.LoadControl(this.MasterControlVirtualPath);

var masterListBox = master.GetListBox();
```

Comment: The problem is to obtain access to the Master.

Comment: That's where you'd put the name of your MasterControl.  If you named the MasterControl MyMasterControl, that's what you'd put in there.

Comment: I have
public partial class Controls_MasterControl1 : UserControl
{ }

public partial class Controls_ChildControl1 : ChildUserControl
{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var master = (Controls_MasterControl1)Page.LoadControl(this.MasterControlVirtualPath);

            var masterListBox = master.GetListBox();

        }
}

Comment: Then put `Controls_MasterControl1` in there.